# Numba: difference between using a factory function vs `cache=True`

Tags: python, caching, numba

Looking for using (and improving execution speed of) a jitted (numba) function having one or several other jitted functions as parameters, I could see in [numbas's FAQ](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/faq.html#programming) the following:

```
dispatching with arguments that are functions has extra overhead. If this matters for your application, you can also use a factory function to capture the function argument in a closure:
```

```py
def make_f(g):
    # Note: a new f() is created each time make_f() is called!
    @jit(nopython=True)
    def f(x):
        return g(x) + g(-x)
    return f

f = make_f(jitted_g_function)
result = f(1)
```

Please, my questions are:

- What happens in the inside of numba then?
- What is the difference with using `@njit(cache=True)`?
- Ultimately, is it advised to use both, a factory function and `cache=True`?

```py
def make_f(g):
    @njit(cache=True)
    def f(x):
        return g(x) + g(-x)
    return f
```

To provide a bit more insight on my actual use case, it has a slightly more increased complexity. The closure would look like this:

```py
from numba import njit, literal_unroll
from numpy import zeros

def make_f(tup):
    @njit
    def f(x):
        # 'x' is a 2d array
        res = zeros((3,x.shape[1]), dtype=x.dtype)
        slice_start = 0
        third_of_x = int(len(x)/3)
        slice_ends = (third_of_x, third_of_x * 2, len(x))
        for i in range(3):
            slice_end = slice_ends[i]
            for item in literal_unroll(tup):
                cols, func = item
                res[i, cols] = func(x[slice_start:slice_end,cols])
            slice_start = slice_end
        return res
    return f
```

With `tup` being a tuple of tuples of columns indices and a callable. for instance:

```py
tup=(
     (np.array([0,2], dtype="int64"), np.sum),
     (np.array([1,3], dtype="int64"), np.max)
    )
```

I am aware in the example, it does not make much sense to slice in 3 `x` row-wise.
But in my actual use case, each chunk is of a 'specific type'. Calculation for this chunk is dependent about what is the type of the previous chunk and what is the type of the current chunk.
So I need to operate row chunk by row chunk, one after the other.

If looking at the 'real' code is necessary, I am speaking about the [`jcsagg` function](https://github.com/yohplala/oups/blob/0987194cb44dd48fd6faf622eb689cf3bba75355/oups/jcumsegagg.py#L220) (currently not in a factory function) within [`oups` project](https://github.com/yohplala/oups).
`jcsagg()` is then called by the non-jitted [`cumsegagg` function](https://github.com/yohplala/oups/blob/0987194cb44dd48fd6faf622eb689cf3bba75355/oups/cumsegagg.py).

Thanks for your advise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens in the inside of numba then?

`make_f` creates a function `f` which is then provided to Numba so to build an object meant to generate a compiled function (but the function is not directly compiled thanks to lazy compilation). Then, `make_f` returns the Numba object and `f(1)` actually compile the function based on the object `f`. The function is compiled based on its parameter and compilation flags. Here there is one integer parameter so Numba will generate a function with the signature `ReturnType(int_)` where `ReturnType` is the one of `jitted_g_function`. Once compiled, the target function will have **one signature** and calling `make_f` with other parameter will not affect the Numba object nor the target function. This can improve performance when `f` is called repetitively since the Numba wrapper needs to check the input type and find which signature match with the provided parameter. **Having more signature should typically increase the matching time**. I expect this overhead to be relatively small though (except for very quick function calls). Note that calling `f` with different input type will increase the number of signature for the target object `f`.

If you use 1 main Numba object for many kind of calls (with the usual method), then the number of signature can increase and **the overhead of the wrapper might be an issue if the function is compiled for many different input types**.

AFAIK, the `g` object is wrapped in the Numba object because `f` is a closure and objects coming from the parent function (or global ones) are assumed to be constant so the compiler could generate a faster code (specialised for the target object). Using the dispatch trick enable the user to generate N different `f` functions using N different `g` function while having fast calls to `g` (because of the specialization, which is also expensive since `f` is recompiled N times independently).

> What is the difference with using `@njit(cache=True)`?

`cache=True` is meant to store the JIT compilation result so it is not recompiled when the Python script is run again later, that is **between multiple execution of the interpreter**. The above method does not provide such a feature.

> Ultimately, is it advised to use both, a factory function and cache=True?

No. A least, not without specific needs. The dispatching trick can significantly increase the compilation time and the `cache=True` also has an overhead. For a large-scale application such overhead can become pretty huge. If the compilation time is an issue, then it might be a better solution to use an AOT compiler instead (although it has some strong limitations so far like AFAIK not supporting fast-math nor parallel codes). Cython can also be an alternative in this case. `cache=True` is typically a good idea when you build a scientific application iteratively (you typically do not want all fonctions to be recompiled every time you test your simulation). Note that AOT compilers are not as flexible as JIT compilers especially when it comes to dynamic operations (everything needs to be compiled before the application is actually run).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! It does help me better understand! Thanks!